# Actor and Future: Referring to an actor message within onComplete

Tags: scala, akka, future

While refactoring actor codes written by some other programmers, I encountered the usage of `Future.onComplete` callback within actor `A`, which goes against the best practice of using `akka.pattern.pipe`. It's a bad idea since it exposes the possibility of race conditions as the `Future` instance might be executed on a different thread.

Looking at the code, we see that  there are neither `sender` nor any mutable `var`s being referred within the `onComplete` block so it seems pretty safe, at least for *this specific occasion*. However, one grey area that leaves me wondering are the references to `url` and especially `text`.

Is it possible that similar to the [Closing Over An Akka Actor Sender In The Receive](http://helenaedelson.com/?p=879) problem, a race condition happens such that at the time when the `onComplete` callback is invoked, the value of `text` already refers to a different actor message, causing all hells to break loose?

```
class B extends akka.actor.Actor {
  def receive = {
    case urlAndText: (String, String) => // do something
  }
}

class A extends akka.actor.Actor {
  case class Insert(url: String)

  def fileUpload(content: String): String = ??? // returns the url of the uploaded content
  val b = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[B]))
  def receive = {
    case text: String =>
      Future {
        fileUpload(text)
      } onComplete {
        case Success(url) =>
          b ! Insert(url, text) // will this be
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference to `text` should be fine. The difference is that each "instance" of `text` is a new variable bound to the scope of the current match block (starting at `case text ...`). Thus the `Future` created closes over the value of `text` just fine.

This is different from `sender` (or `sender()` when de-sugared) which is actually a method defined on the `Actor` trait which returns the `ActorRef` of the sender of the most recent message received by the actor on which it is called, and so can give a different value when called later (when the `Future`'s `onComplete` is finally called).

You are right to be suspect about the use of `onComplete`, too. A better option would be:

```
case text: String =>
  Future {
    fileUpload(text)
  } map { url => 
    Insert(url, text) 
  } pipeTo b
```

Now failures will also be sent on to `b`, rather than being quietly swallowed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you aren't going to run into any race conditions although as you noted it is not a particularly good idea to structure code this way in general.

The references to both `url` and `text` are fine. The value for `url` is simply an extraction of a successfully completed Future and that doesn't change whether you're in an Actor or not. The value for `text` is an immutable string and closing over that value in a Future shouldn't cause problems because that string instance is immutable.

As you noted closing over `sender` or a var is a problem and that's because being mutable objects those values could change by the time the Future completes unlike immutable values which will remain constant even when you close over them.